# Zend framework on shared hosting can't load images css and js

Tags: zend-framework, hosting, shared-hosting

Hello i have some project. From my hoster i can't modify document root so i have some directory like"mysite.com"
I copy my project to this folder. And put to my document root .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

And now, mvc works fine but. If i load _http://mysite.com/css/images/header.jpg i have error file not found. But this file i have in /public/css/images.
Also if i put 1.php file to my /public/css/images/ If i take _http://mysite.com/css/images/1.php it load my php file. So Help please what to do for including this image to my progect. 
P.S http://mysite.com/public/images/header.jpg work greate. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `baseUrl` view helper would help:

```
<?= $this->baseUrl('/some/css/path.css') ?>
```

Comment: does not work. If i use this i need to change all my css js etc